# Avoiding Service Locator Antipattern with HTTP Request Lifetime Scope and Global Filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, autofac

I have a global filter attribute that needs access to an item that is registerd per HTTP request:

```
// other ContainerBuilder stuff
builder.RegisterType<HttpDependency>().As<IHttpDependency>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

And elsewhere:

```
internal sealed class MyActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // EVIL YUCKY SERVICE LOCATOR!
        var resolved = AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.RequestLifetimeScope.Resolve<IHttpDependency>();

        if (resolved.NeedsRedirect)
        {
            // does a redirect
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

And registering it as a global filter:

```
// in FilterConfig.cs
filters.Add(new MyActionFilter());
```

Since this is a global filter, I can't use constructor injection, i.e. the HTTP context on app startup shouldn't get reused for *every request*. How can I wire this up properly without resorting to reaching out and grabbing it via a service locator?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there *is* HTTP Context on app startup.  That is, the `Application.Start` event is triggered by an HTTP request, and `HttpContext.Current` is not null.  But, I don't know anything about autofac, so I may be misunderstanding you.

Comment: Whether or not there is an HTTP context at app startup doesn't really matter. I need to resolve the dependency at runtime within the context of the *current* HTTP context, not the one that existed at app startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to remove your logic from the Attribute and implement it in a class that implements IActionFilter.  The class is then registered with the container so that dependency injection will work correctly.  Orchard CMS using this approach.

```
public class MyCustomActionFilterAttribute : Attribute
{
}

public class MyCustomActionFilter : FilterProvider, IActionFilter
{
    protected MyService Service { get; private set; }

    // MyService can be injected by the container...
    public MyCustomActionFilter(MyService service)
    {
        this.Service = service;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        // Check to see if the action has a matching attribute
        var attributes = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyCustomActionFilterAttribute), true);

        // Perform some logic here....
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
    }
}
```

It is possible to create an IActionInvoker that applies the filter to the action, this class is automatically instantiated my MVC using the DependencyResolver.

```
public class FilterResolvingActionInvoker : ControllerActionInvoker
{
    protected IEnumerable<IFilterProvider> Providers { get; private set; }

    // Filters registered with the container are injected by the container
    public FilterResolvingActionInvoker(IEnumerable<IFilterProvider> providers)
    {
        this.Providers = providers;
    }

    // Add the filter to the current FilterInfo
    protected override FilterInfo GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        var filters = base.GetFilters(controllerContext, actionDescriptor);
        foreach (var provider in this.Providers)
        {
            provider.AddFilters(filters);
        }
        return filters;
    }
}
```

Define a common interface that allows us to register our filters.

```
public interface IFilterProvider
{
    void AddFilters(FilterInfo filterInfo);
}

public abstract class FilterProvider : IFilterProvider
{
    public void AddFilters(FilterInfo filterInfo)
    {
        if (this is IActionFilter)
        {
            filterInfo.ActionFilters.Add(this as IActionFilter);
        }
    }
}
```

And register them with the container builder.  It is also possible to create an extension method for Autofac to automatically register all IFilterProviders in your assembly.

```
builder.RegisterType<FilterResolvingActionInvoker>().As<IActionInvoker>().InstancePerDependency();
builder.RegisterType<MyCustomActionFilter>().As<IFilterProvider>().InstancePerDependency();
```

Comment: I think the piece I was missing here was the `IActionInvoker` interface getting activated from the `DependencyResolver`. Am I understanding correctly that we're achieving the same goal by circumventing the built-in global filter mechanism in MVC?

Answer (score -1):

As always, one of the options to avoid the locator is to have a local factory which is set up in the Compositon Root. The factory is set up so that it uses your ioc container.

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2012/12/di-factories-and-composition-root.html

Although you could argue that "technically" this "looks like" locator (you create a factory instance and ask it for the service), it doesn't introduce any dependencies to any other infrastructure including the actual IoC container you ultimately use to implement the factory - the implementation of the actual factory is a part of the Composition Root (somewhere near the global application class).

Such approach leads to a lot of isolated small factories responsible for parts of your infrastructure but still each factory has a pluggable provider you can implement near the Composition Root thus avoiding any external dependencies.

Comment: In this particular case, I had (and threw away) an implementation where I let Autofac create the `Func<IHttpDependency>` for me, but it gave me the wrong `HttpContext` repeatedly, which leads me to doubt that it's properly resolving via the currently-applicable `ILifetimeScope`. The magic piece here is having the (effectively) global object's injected factory resolve based on the currently-applicable `ILifetimeScope` that corresponds to the current HTTP context.

Comment: I don't know AutoFac but from what I google, you can register an expression which would evaluate each time a service is resolved like builder.Register( c => here goes your code that uses HttpContext.Current ).As<IHttpDependency>().InstancePerHttpRequest();